# StaffMiddleware And AdminMiddleware Laravel 5.3

Tags: laravel, middleware

I have 2 Middlewares.

My StaffMiddleware

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if( $request->user()->role->name != 'staff'){

        return redirect()->route('store');
    }
    return $next($request);
}
```

My AdminMiddleware

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if( $request->user()->role->name != 'admin'){

        return redirect()->route('store');
    }
    return $next($request);
}
```

The Problem is my UnitController

```
public function __construct(UnitInterface $unit){

        $this->middleware('staff');
        $this->middleware('admin);
        $this->unit = $unit;
    }
```

It should work either the role is a staff or an admin. Do I need to create another Middleware to combine them both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This completely depends on the way your Middleware is designed.  As you can see from your code, it simple redirects if the role is not staff or not admin so there would be no way for you to have an OR logic.

However, you could use middleware parameters to avoid this.

```
    $this->middleware('role:admin,staff');
```

This will use the `role` middleware and pass `admin` and `staff` as parameters.

Then you can use these parameters in your middleware:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, ...$params)
{
    if(!in_array($request->user()->role->name, $params)){

        return redirect()->route('store');
    }
    return $next($request);
}
```

This captures the additional parameters into an array `$params` in which you can check if the user's role matches one of the parameters.

Comment: Yes I know, Can we implement "admin OR staff"? If it has a role of admin or staff then, no problem else redirect.

Comment: @Rbex, I have updated my answer to show how you can use parameters to make your middleware more flexible.  It would require a change to your middleware, but would only require one middleware instead of a variety of combinations for roles.

Comment: That's what I'm looking for... Thumbs up!

Answer (score 0):

```
**try this**

public function __construct(UnitInterface $unit){

      $this->middleware(function ($request, $next) {
        if($request->user()->role->name == 'staff' || $request->user()->role->name == 'admin')
          {
            return $next($request);
          }
           return redirect()->route('store')
        });
    }
```

No middleware